# I use [es6-modules] but I don't want to be accused of modul[esm]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

There are a few people who *really* want to use the abbreviation ESM (and therefore the tag [esm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esm)) to mean ECMAScript Modules, even though we have the tag [es6-modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es6-modules) for that feature.

[esm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esm) has no wiki or excerpt and has somewhere around 70 questions.

I think a synonym [esm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esm) -> [es6-modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es6-modules) ([es6-modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es6-modules) as the result of typing "esm") would be sufficient, but as I don't have the requisite score, I am making this request.

Comment: A quick analysis of potential use cases for where [tag:esm] is used to mean something else than [tag:es6-modules] showed nothing, so I supposed it is safe to just go directly for the synonym